# Visio will not save changes when I reorder pages in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, visio

I am trying to reorder the pages in Visio using VSTO(C# addin). The code below does this. The "pageList" is a Linq list of Visio Page objects. The "movement" variable is telling the loop how many times to move the index position of the page in the list. The Move method takes a list, the index of the item I want to move, and which direction.The Move Method moves it by 1 either Up or Down.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= movement; i++)
{
    int listIndex = pageList.FindIndex(x => x == page);
    Converter.Move(pageList,listIndex,moveDirection);
}
```

Next is after I shuffle around the pages in the list, I then change their actual index in Visio according to the position they are in. Visio indexing starts at a base of 1 instead of 0.

```
for (int i = pageList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    pageList[i].Index = (short)(i + 1);
}
```

When I run this, it performs the indexing correctly. The example I have below, shows that the page "Women 144" is at index 5(it was orignally at index 16). So visually it looks good. But when I save Visio, close it down, and reopen the document, the page "Women 144" is now at index 9 for some reason. Is there something I'm missing? Why was it good before, but now not?

[image: visio]

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with the [way that the Visio page collection is indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.index). If you change the index of an item in the collection, the other index values are changed to compensate. In your Visio page index assignment loop you decrement with `i--`. This might cause issues depending on the order of operations for Visio's collection organization. I would suggest building the Visio index values in ascending order.

Comment: I think we need to see more code to be clear, but bear in mind that a) the pages collection in Visio is 1 based, (rather than zero) so your reverse loop should be `for (int i = pageList.Count; i > 0; i--)` and b) you will need to check for Background pages as you can't move them and you can't move a Foreground page beyond a background one (background pages are unordered).

Comment: Sadly I did try ascending order as well. And I do end up changing all of the background pages into normal pages as well. I basically gave up on it. Not worth spending another full day on a feature that isn't that crucial.

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith +1 for teaching me that background pages are unordered.